# Why Pandas' iloc and at return different values?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a strange behavior on Pandas. Can anyone explain why at and iloc are returning different values?

The code:

```
df = deepcopy(another dataframe)
print(df.iloc[i]["X"], end="\t")
df.at[i,"X"] = 0.0
print(df.at[i,"X"], end="\t")
print(df.iloc[i]["X"])
```

Gives me:

```
11292.1213952329
0.0
11292.1213952329
```

Why the two last prints are given different results?

Comment: `at` uses label-based lookup (like `loc`). `iloc` uses position-based lookup

Comment: You might want to use `df.iat[i, df.columns.get_loc('X')]` for mixed indexing